# How did the program installer detect my email id?

Tags: windows

I was trying to download Turbo C++ on my PC, and I happened to notice that under 'User Information' it had my email id. I tried downloading the program installer from an Incognito window, thinking that it might have picked it up from my browser (Brave). But it, somehow, still had the email id. It would be wonderful if someone could help me understand what is going on. Thank you :).
P.S. I've attached an image too. [Screenshot of the installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyMKi.png)

Answer (score 0):

Open up a command console.
Type 'set' and return.
You'll probably see a line near the bottom of the list like:
`USERNAME=ddaniels@gmail.com`.

At some point when Windows was installed, that was the user name entered for the installation.

Alternately it might be buried in the registry somewhere ...

Answer (score -2):

It's possible for a program to read user information from Windows including your email address if you are singed into a Microsoft account.

There are other places in the OS where this shows up including the About Windows dialog (`winver`).